# Redirect HTTPS on multidomain Varnish

Tags: ssl, https, varnish, bitnami

i have got two domain based on same framework (magento2)
domain1.it
domain2.com

I would like to redirect them to their respective SSL version.
https://domain1.it
https://domain2.com

Domain 1 is correctly configured to redirect to HTTPS and my varnish Config file is:

```
sub vcl_recv {
if ( (req.http.host ~ "^(?i)www.domain1.it" || req.http.host ~ "^(?i)domain1.it") && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https") {
return (synth(750, ""));
    }

sub vcl_synth {
if (resp.status == 750) {
    set resp.status = 301;
    set resp.http.Location = "https://domain1.it" + req.url;
return(deliver);
}
```

the problem is the synth always redirect to the same domain.

I should add an if condition where i could call a subroutines that redirect to https for domain2

Answer (score 1):

For the love of everything that is good, please stop using otherworldly status codes, 301 and 302 are perfectly fine, clearer and save you a line.

I would advise against using `x-forwarded-proto` and use an SSL/TLS terminator that supports the PROXY protocol, but since this is what you have, here you go:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "https") {
        set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
        return(synth(301));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 301 || resp.status == 302) {
        set resp.http.location = req.http.location;
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

relevant link: https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/rewriting-urls-with-varnish-redirection

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here. I just reviewed the Varnish documentation and found this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (client.ip != "127.0.0.1" && std.port(server.ip) == 80 && req.http.host ~ "^(?i)example.com") {
        set req.http.x-redir = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
        return(synth(850, "Moved permanently"));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 850) {
        set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
        set resp.status = 302;
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

This is useful when you want to redirect the clients to an SSL-version of your site. More info here:

https://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRedirectInVCL